# Authentication ASP.NET MVC 5 against Database

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to `ASP NET MVC authentication` and I have troubles with it on my web Project

By default (as result of project generation) there is an `AccountController` which has a `Login` method

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private UserService _userService;
    public UserService UserService{
        get { return _userService ?? (_userService = new UserService()); }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl){
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        //the line with SignInManager is Default in project
        //var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        //I have implemented my User service which checks in DB is there exists such a user with email and password and returns the same SignInStatus
        var result = UserService.Authenticate(model.Email, model.Password);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

My `UserService` implementation:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public SignInStatus Authenticate(string email, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            return SignInStatus.Failure;
        }

        //TODO: perform authentication against DB account
        if (email == "mymail@mail.com" && password == "123")
        {
            return SignInStatus.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return SignInStatus.Failure;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using it with `[Authorize]` attribute on my `AdministrationController`

```
public class AdministrationController : Controller
{
    // GET: Admin/Admin
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I enter the administration area of my site , via `http://localhost:53194/administration` it does not require any authentication (does not display Login screen)

If I set the attribute `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` on my method

```
public class AdministrationController : Controller
{
    // GET: Admin/Admin
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Login screen** appears. 
I set the **email** and **password**. Pressing on **Login** button it enters the `Login` method from `AccountController`, enters the case with `SignInStatus.Success`

But also the **Login** screen remains. It is not redirected to normal **Administration** screen.

Can you advice me how to implement this Authentication please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have set the authentication cookie upon successful login. So the user actually gets redirected to the Administration page but since he doesn't have a valid authentication cookie, he gets redirected back to the login form.

So make sure that you set the cookie:

```
case SignInStatus.Success:
    var user = new ApplicationUser
    {
        Email = model.Email,
        UserName = model.Email,
        ... set any other properties that you find convenient
    };
    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false, false);
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. This makes sense. I have to add the user in cookie. I added the lines you suggested, but also it stays at Login Page without be allowed to enter normal Administration view. Maybe is because I use the Attribute `[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]`. Should I add some logic to add Roles for this user? Or Somehow It is necessary to change the attribute ?

Comment: Yes, of course, you should assign this user the Administrators role if you are going to require it.

Comment: actually if I use the [Authorize] without Roles, it does not 'fire' the Login process. Is it possible somehow to 'fire' the Login process by using this attribute but without roles ?

Comment: When you decorate a controller or action with the `[Authorize]` attribute, then ASP.NET MVC will check whether the request is associated with a valid cookie containing a user. When you decorate a controller or action with `[Authorize(Roles = "foobar")]` then ASP.NET MVC will  check in addition that the current user has the required role. So if you don't care about roles, then don't use them: `[Authorize]`. I would also recommend you reading some tutorials about ASP.NET Identity if you intend to use it.

Comment: If I use [Authorize] the Login Page is not shown. I don't know why.  Do you know something around that maybe? Thanks for recommendation. I will read of course!